# silverstripe permissions - prevent dataobject from being edited

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

at the moment I´m checking out the canEdit and canDelete Functions of Dataobject. As far as I can see I have to call that functions always manually in the template or other php code... Is there a way to prevent editing/deleting in general for a certain Dataobject? When I saw the canEdit function the first time I expected it to be checked by silverstripe automatically before writing the DataObject.

So I just want ADMINS to be allowed to write this DataObject:

```
public function canEdit($member = null){
    return(
        Permission::checkMember($member = Member::currentUser(), 'ADMIN')
    );
}
```

Regards,
Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function canEdit($member){
  if (Permission::check('ADMIN')){
      return true;
  }else{
     // do something here if applicable 
  } 
}
```

[Reference Link 1](http://www.silverstripe.org/data-model-questions/show/6059)

[Reference Link 2](http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/16894)

[Reference Link 3](http://www.balbuss.com/adding-new-group-permissions/)

Comment: I still wonder where this exactly applies. If I say canEdit(){return false} in the DataObject Class, then the Controller can still edit the DataObjects... or do I have to call that function canEdit() manually in the controller, e.g. before saving the dataobject?

Comment: Can you please put sample code in http://www.sspaste.com/ .... and give the link here. Basically you write in class extending dataobject.

Comment: Paste some code and give the scenario what you want to achieve. That will be helpful for me to help you out. Please specify the silverstripe version also. Thanks

Comment: here the paste of the DataObject class: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/50e42931533f0
I just wonder how I can set the permissions globally for that DataObject. So for example that a new Dataobject can just be created If you are logged In as ADMIN. But to me it looks like that I always have to call the e.g. canCreate class manually, to see if the current User has the permission to create the DataObject. Silverstripe does not check this automatically before creating one of that DataObjects. True?

Comment: Put this code in your DataObject Class

public function canEdit($member){
      if (Permission::check('ADMIN')){
          return false;
      }
}

Then logged in as Admin, Can you edit the DataObject? If you see, edit button will be removed from grid list view. 

This functionality is working when you are using Backend GUI. If permission methods like canView / canEdit returns true then you will be able to perform the operation.

If you are not using GUI, then you have to check whether the current user has permission or not when directly interacting via your code.

Comment: ok for me it´s a frontend thing. so I have to do the permission checks manually e.g. calling and checking canEdit before saving an dataobject. thx